# Can socat be started directly by systemd?

Tags: systemd, socat

The following [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat) command-line works as expected when entered at a shell prompt:

```
# /usr/bin/socat UDP-RECV:4321 STDOUT
```

It listens on UDP port 4321 and writes everything received to standard output.

The following is an attempt at starting this command as a systemd service with the intention that it writes received data to the systemd journal (the default destination for a service's standard output):

```
# /etc/systemd/system/socat.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat UDP-RECV:4321 STDOUT
```

However, socat exits immediately when this service is started:

```
Process: 7425 ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat UDP-RECV:4321 STDOUT (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Researching the problem (running `socat` with `-d -d -d -d`) revals that it's getting an EOF on standard output:

```
N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [1,1]
N socket 2 (fd 1) is at EOF
I close(5)
N exiting with status 0
```

Is it possible to use `socat` as a systemd service?

Comment: Of course you can run `socat` as a systemd service, there's nothing that stops you from doing that. But I really wonder what are your expectations regarding the `stdout` stream. You certainly don't expect a system service to be connected with a terminal session, do you?

Comment: I know I can _of course_ run socat as a systemd service. But something is causing it to exit and that looks like an EOF on stdout. I _certainly don't expect a systemd service to be connected with a terminal session_. If you know anything about systemd then you'll know that processes' stdouts are by default connected to the journal... just like I said in my question.

Comment: Relax, no need for confrontation. I see there's now an accepted answer and is indeed related to the standard streams, so nothing unexpected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is due to `socat` being bi-directional by default. It attempts to read its standard input which is `/dev/null`, it gets an EOF and exits.

The solution is to use the `-u` option:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat -u UDP-RECV:4321 STDOUT
```

This tells socat to run unidirectionally from `UDP-RECV:4321` to `STDOUT`.